# Considerations when activating WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress

I have Civi for WordPress installed on the main domain of our site and have multiple other WordPress installations on various subdomains. To streamline things a bit, I'm preparing to enable WPMS. I was wondering if there are any special considerations I need to make to ensure Civi doesn't get broken somehow. It doesn't need to share data with any of the other sites.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to be aware that Civi doesn't fully work with WPMS as yet. You *can* Network Enable it, but the Civi backend will not function as expected on sites other than the main site. There are workarounds, but since you aren't using on sub-sites then you should be fine if you just enable it on the main site.

Comment: I have found that it is best to enable on the site you are using CiviCRM on.  Typically the main site, but not always.  We have also implemented CiviCRM Multi-Site following this:  http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation   You still need to activate per site (network activate will fail) but it does work.  We've also user org.civicrm.multisite to help with permissioning.